# how do I POST a jpeg to a web form the way a browser would?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, post, file-upload

I need to upload a file to a form. This is a generic browser based upload I want to mimic. I have looked through the HTML documentation but I can't figure out how it works.

right now I am using a URL to submit the rest of the form information "www.domain.com/form.html?field=value&field2=value2".

This is all there is to the HTML for the file upload.

```
<input type="file" name="Attach" />
```

I want to upload a jpeg so I changed the data to jpeg with this:

```
NSData *attachImage;
attachImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 90);
```

Now I need to send the server the image information and file name while still giving it the rest of the URL.
I have found a couple of examples of people doing this to a php file but none that actually mimic how a web browser would do it.

Answer (score 0):

look at classic sample:

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload

Comment: Thanks Valdimir, but I spent a few hours playing with a few of the examples and I am no closer to understanding this then when I started. There must be a way to just include all of the data in the url right?
&Attach=reallyreallyreallyreallyreallylongdatastring&somefield=vale.
It must be able to be that simple I am just not sure how to wrap up the data inside a string to include the file name. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You should clarify for yourself what submission method you need. There are two methods GET and POST,
both can be used to submit forms and it depends on server-side script which one you should use.
Using GET method you provide parameters in URL like: http://site.com/program?name1
=value1&name2=value2. But you can not use GET methods to submit binary file contents. And must use
POST method, where you provide data in request body. Sample at
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUploadSample is  working code, just add single file to you
project and use initWithURL:... method